# Apache is not loading PHP.ini

Tags: php, apache

Okay this is a beginner problem but I can't seem to find a solution to it. I've ran `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and confirmed my php.ini path. Restarted Apache server after making changes in php.ini but still Apache is not accepting changes i've made in php.ini. I can't load extensions, change error reporting status, etc. Where else should i look, what else should i do in order to make Apache work with my php.ini? (p.s: PHP works fine so I don't think there is a problem with LoadModule in httpd.conf)

Also, this is my phpinfo output: http://jsbin.com/ipilom and this is my php.ini in that path: http://paste2.org/p/2133057

Comment: What changes did you try to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure that those settings such as error reporting is not overriden in PHP scripts?

Comment: Are you running PHP in CGI/FastCGI mode? Start from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Comment: @user871784 I'm tryin to install roundcube (webmail client) so I tried to enable exif, fileinfo, intl and mbstring extensions. Even if I erase php.ini content completely and restart Apache it doesn't matter, there is no change.

Comment: may be you are changing in wrong location.. or you don't have permission to modify php.ini

Comment: hm did you run phpinfo() on the webserver or on the commandline?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta Like I said, I've checked php.ini location from phpinfo and changed its content successfully in my vps.

Comment: @user871784 I've created a php file (lets say test.php) and wrote <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it, then i typed the url for that php and read the output.

Comment: @gcx if that's the case, and you cleared whole php.ini, your PHP pages will not run. Please provide code you wrote to enable extensions like you said mbstring, etc..

Comment: ok so you definitley are editing the right php.ini...how did you restart apache?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta This is my phpinfo output: http://jsbin.com/ipilom and this is my php.ini in that path: http://paste2.org/p/2133057

Comment: @user871784 Did it with Apache Monitor and also manually in services.msc by clicking start and stop. Also I'm sure I'm restarting the correct service since it goes down when i stop and goes up when I start it.

Comment: ok you juast need to make sure the http daemon is restarted because thats the one which is actually loading the php.ini

Comment: "Apache is not loading PHP.ini" -- apache will never load php.ini.

Comment: can you give the file path where you are changing your php.ini?

Comment: Your php.ini is read from `C:\Windows\php.ini` by apache

Comment: @Flavius Can you tell me what is the right term, so I won't be mistaken again?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta That's the file I'm changing.

Answer (score 4):

check if your ftp user owns the file (it will usually belong to root)

```
sudo chown ubuntu /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sudo chown ubuntu /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

change "ubuntu" for your userName and "/etc/php5/apache2/" for the path indicated in phpInfo()

then restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

should do the trick

Comment: It was actually chmod that fixed it, but this put me on the right track - the other group needs (r)ead permissions.

Comment: **Reboot your whole machine** and the problem goes away.  LAMP stacks often get glitched, and restarting apache just straight up refuses to load any new php.ini until after a machine reboot.  It's sad that linux has to go back to the old days of Windows Vista and Windows ME where: "Reboot your computer" is the never ending chorus.

Comment: @EricLeschinski thats the vintage vw beetle motto.  Ive been coding since the trs80 and its a trick sometimes saves the day, especially when nothing makes sense anymore.

Answer (score 2):

what is `phpinfo()` telling you in the row *Configuration File (php.ini)*?
what operating system are your running?

make sure your php.ini is located inside of that directory.
additionally, you might want to check file permissions.
the user your apache runs with must be able to read `php.ini`.

Comment: This is my phpinfo output: jsbin.com/ipilom and this is my php.ini in that path: paste2.org/p/2133057. My user, that runs Apache, has administrator priviliges. Also php.ini is located in that path.

Comment: please, have a look at roundcube's `.htaccess` file (i believe it is a hidden file on windows; in the root folder of your roundcube installation). those settings override any php.ini settings. they sit between apache's configuration and roundcube's runtime settings. also, make sure you REALLY completely restarted apache.

Answer (score 1):

based on my experience, you may need to make sure that

PHPIniDir "C:\php54\" in apache httpd.conf

is proper configured, sometimes the '\' or '/' could be very tricky.